# tomcat application missing displayname

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a little project with some jsp deployed on an Tomcat 5.5. Recently the Servlets which are also deployed with the jsp files (one war archive) stopped working. I also checked out a previous version from my svn which should work. What I noticed that the `displayname` (I use a german version of Tomcat , so I guess that is how I would translate it, the name in the second column in the Tomcat manager) disappeared. I use Eclipse Ganymede on vista. Tomcat is running on Debian. A local Tomcat shows the same behavior.
Hope someone have an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is the `<display-name>` element in the web.xml file? Is the `web.xml` file in the WAR and at `/WEB-INF/web.xml`? Does it validate (eclipse can do that, or try [w3c.org's validation service](http://validator.w3.org/))?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for

```
<web-app blahblah>
    <display-name>**This**</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Not this</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the deployment descriptor for your application. i.e. web.xml. Usually, when an application is deployed but does not start its because of either a misconfig or not well formed web.xml.